# ruby inside JavaScript gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building presentation builder and trying to write data from params into JavaScript object $("#data-store").
Everything goes smoothly, but the problems appear with @content. It contains the html for one slide. When I try to use  parent.$("#data-store").data("content[<%=n%>]", "<%= @content[n.to_s].html_safe %>" ); in console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier appear.

```
  var fillUpData = function() {
       if ( $.isEmptyObject(parent.$("#data-store").data())) {
         console.log("empty")
         parent.$("#data-store").data("wallpaper", "<%= @wallpaper %>" );
         parent.$("#data-store").data("imageNum", "<%= @imageNum %>" );
          <% @num_slides.times do |n| %> 
         parent.$("#data-store").data("background[<%=n%>]", "<%= @background[n.to_s] %>" );
         parent.$("#data-store").data("content[<%=n%>]", "<%= @content[n.to_s].html_safe %>" );
          <% end %>
         // parent.$("#data-store").data("data", [<%= @datastore.html_safe %>]);
          } else {
        console.log("notempty");
        }
      }
```

I think It might be a problem with the data structure in @content.
params for @content looks lik that:

```
"content"=>{"0"=>"<img id=\"link2\" style=\"position: absolute\" src=\"http://i.imgur.com/X0XCFys.png \"><div class=\"editor\" contenteditable=\"true\" style=\"position: absolute; left: 743px; top: 312px;\"><h2 class=\"text2\">Title</h2></div><div class=\"ui-wrapper ui-draggable\" style=\"overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 128px; height: 128px; top: 225.1111125946045px; left: 508.1111145019531px; margin: 0px;\"><img id=\"link1\" style=\"position: static; margin: 0px; resize: none; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 128px; width: 128px;\" src=\"http://i.imgur.com/qTXDZhT.png \" class=\"ui-resizable\"><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><img class=\"icon-layer-up icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_up.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-layer-down icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_down.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-trash1 icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_trash.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-copy-el icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_copy.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-layer-up icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_up.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-layer-down icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_down.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-trash1 icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_trash.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-copy-el icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_copy.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"></div>\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        ", "1"=>"\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        ", "2"=>"\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        ", "3"=>"\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        ", "4"=>"\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        ", "5"=>"\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        ", "6"=>"\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        ", "7"=>"\r\n                    \r\n         \r\n    \r\n        "},
```

when I inspect this function in console I am getting something like this:

```
 var fillUpData = function() {
   if ( $.isEmptyObject(parent.$("#data-store").data())) {
     console.log("empty")
     parent.$("#data-store").data("wallpaper", "http://i.imgur.com/cRrY9Fk.png" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("text", "" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("imageNum", "1" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[0]", "url(http://i.imgur.com/nYkdOne.png)" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[0]", "<div class="editor ui-resizable ui-draggable" contenteditable="true" style="position: absolute; left: 298.1111602783203px; top: 193.09722900390625px;"><h2 class="text2">Titsadasdle</h2><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div><img class="icon-layer-up2 icon-on-edit" src="/assets/icon_layer_up.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-down2 icon-on-edit" src="/assets/icon_layer_down.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-trash2 icon-on-edit" src="/assets/icon_trash.png" style="z-index: 2;"><i class="icon-move icon-on-edit" style="z-index: 2;"></i><i class="icon-font font2 icon-on-edit" style="z-index: 2;"></i><img class="icon-font-size icon-on-edit" src="/assets/font_size2.png" style="z-index: 2;"></div><div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 128px; height: 128px; top: 285.1111125946045px; left: 52.111114501953125px; margin: 0px;"><img id="link1" style="position: static; margin: 0px; resize: none; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 128px; width: 128px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/qTXDZhT.png " class="ui-resizable"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div><img class="icon-layer-up icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_up.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-down icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_down.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-trash1 icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_trash.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-copy-el icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_copy.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-up icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_up.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-down icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_down.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-trash1 icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_trash.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-copy-el icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_copy.png" style="z-index: 2;"></div>



    " );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[1]", "url(http://i.imgur.com/zXJv24z.png)" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[1]", "



    " );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[2]", "" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[2]", "



    " );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[3]", "" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[3]", "



    " );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[4]", "" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[4]", "



    " );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[5]", "" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[5]", "



    " );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[6]", "" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[6]", "



    " );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("background[7]", "" );
     parent.$("#data-store").data("content[7]", "



    " );
      } else {
    console.log("notempty");
    }
  }
```

what can I do to being able to write params for each content into JavaScript object data()?

Comment: Look at the generated HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Your generated HTML has a problem:

```js
parent.$("#data-store").data("content[0]", "<div class="editor ui-resizable ui-draggable" contenteditable="true" style="position: absolute; left: 298.1111602783203px; top: 193.09722900390625px;"><h2 class="text2">Titsadasdle</h2><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div><img class="icon-layer-up2 icon-on-edit" src="/assets/icon_layer_up.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-down2 icon-on-edit" src="/assets/icon_layer_down.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-trash2 icon-on-edit" src="/assets/icon_trash.png" style="z-index: 2;"><i class="icon-move icon-on-edit" style="z-index: 2;"></i><i class="icon-font font2 icon-on-edit" style="z-index: 2;"></i><img class="icon-font-size icon-on-edit" src="/assets/font_size2.png" style="z-index: 2;"></div><div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 128px; height: 128px; top: 285.1111125946045px; left: 52.111114501953125px; margin: 0px;"><img id="link1" style="position: static; margin: 0px; resize: none; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 128px; width: 128px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/qTXDZhT.png " class="ui-resizable"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div><img class="icon-layer-up icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_up.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-down icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_down.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-trash1 icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_trash.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-copy-el icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_copy.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-up icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_up.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-layer-down icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_layer_down.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-trash1 icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_trash.png" style="z-index: 2;"><img class="icon-copy-el icon-on-img" src="/assets/icon_copy.png" style="z-index: 2;"></div>")
//                                                     ^ etc.
```

There ae unescaped quotes throwing spanners in the works. Calling `.html_safe` isn't enough here; you'll need to run the HTML through a bit of code to replace `"` with `\"`. Fortunately, this is a simple task:

```rb
tmp = @content[n.to_s].html_safe
begin
  # regex matches a double-quote not preceded by a backslash
  tmp[/(?<!\\)"/] = '\\"' while true
rescue
  # the regex failed; all quotes are now escaped (or no quotes in the first place)
end
# now echo tmp
```

```js
parent.$("#data-store").data("content[0]", "<div class=\"editor ui-resizable ui-draggable\" contenteditable=\"true\" style=\"position: absolute; left: 298.1111602783203px; top: 193.09722900390625px;\"><h2 class=\"text2\">Titsadasdle</h2><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><img class=\"icon-layer-up2 icon-on-edit\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_up.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-layer-down2 icon-on-edit\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_down.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-trash2 icon-on-edit\" src=\"/assets/icon_trash.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><i class=\"icon-move icon-on-edit\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"></i><i class=\"icon-font font2 icon-on-edit\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"></i><img class=\"icon-font-size icon-on-edit\" src=\"/assets/font_size2.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"></div><div class=\"ui-wrapper ui-draggable\" style=\"overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 128px; height: 128px; top: 285.1111125946045px; left: 52.111114501953125px; margin: 0px;\"><img id=\"link1\" style=\"position: static; margin: 0px; resize: none; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 128px; width: 128px;\" src=\"http://i.imgur.com/qTXDZhT.png \" class=\"ui-resizable\"><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><div class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se\" style=\"z-index: 90;\"></div><img class=\"icon-layer-up icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_up.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-layer-down icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_down.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-trash1 icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_trash.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-copy-el icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_copy.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-layer-up icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_up.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-layer-down icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_layer_down.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-trash1 icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_trash.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"><img class=\"icon-copy-el icon-on-img\" src=\"/assets/icon_copy.png\" style=\"z-index: 2;\"></div>")
```

You can use a similar strategy to escape anything else that JavaScript might complain about.

Comment: I got error regexp not matched when I try to do it like that:   parent.$("#data-store").data("content[<%=n%>]", "<%= @content[n.to_s].html_safe[/"/] = '\\"' %>" );

Comment: @lipenco Odd... I'll do some further testing and let you know.

Comment: thanks, I think it might be the problem with the part of code which is making a new line in ruby code.   \\r\\n         \\r\\n    \\r\\n        \"\n  '4': ! \"\\r\\n                    \\r\\n         \\r\\n    \\r\\n  i am not sure is it is reduced by .html_safe

Comment: @lipenco I improved the code, and I believe the improvements fixed the regex error as well.

Comment: thanks for that,for now I am using : parent.$("#data-store").data("content[<%=n%>]", "<%= @content[n.to_s].squish %>"); which is not giving me errors, but while printing it like that:   @content[n.to_s].html_safe it will give me a quotes around and the html is shown as a text. How can I remove this quotes while printing it?

Comment: @lipenco As documented [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/String/squish), `String#squish` just gets rid of unnecessary whitespace. This is good, but you'll still need to use `.html_safe` and the quote-escaping block afterwards.

Comment: yes, but <%= @content[n.to_s].squish.html_safe %> is giving me JS errors, so it might be better to just get rid of qotes when I am using params in code like that   <div class="step-wrapper">
                    
         <%=
            if @content.nil? || @content[n.to_s].nil?
            else
              @content[n.to_s].html_safe
    
            end
          %>
    
        </div>

Comment: @lipenco This may seem an obvious question, but have you used the quote-escaping block after using `.squish.html_safe`?